# Why does the meaning of "above" seem to change when my "shift" coordinate changes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

The only difference between these two examples is the size of the `xshift`.

The  MWE with `xshift=-1.5in` and `xshift=-1.0in` places the text where I expect, but not with `xshift=-0.75in` and `xshift=-0.5in`:

[image]

Could someone explain why the interpretation of `above` is being changed?

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\MyTixZPicture}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={xshift=#1}]

    \node [above left] at (0,0) {\texttt{xshift=$#1$}};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:B}] (B) at (0,-3in) {};  

  \node[circle,inner sep=1pt] 
    (C) at ($([c]A)!0.5!([c]B)$) {C} 
      edge [->,blue] node [midway,above,red,sloped] {to the top}     ([c]A) 
      edge [->,gray] node [midway,above,blue,sloped] {to the bottom} ([c]B);

  \foreach \myn  in {A,B}
    {
      \draw ([c]\myn) ++ (-8pt,0) -- (\myn)   ;
    }

\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}

\MyTixZPicture{-1.5in}
\MyTixZPicture{-1.0in}
\MyTixZPicture{-0.75in}
\MyTixZPicture{-0.5in}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I was having difficulty seeing the effect so made the picture a macro. Please revert the edit if you don't like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with internal rounding in the `calc` library. If we leave the calculations out of it, everything works as expected (see the "correct!" and "also correct!" texts):

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\MyTixZPicture}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={xshift=#1}]

    \node [above left] at (0,0) {$\texttt{xshift}=#1$};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:B}] (B) at (0,-3in) {};  

  \node[circle,inner sep=1pt] 
    (C) at ($([c]A)!0.5!([c]B)$) {C} 
      edge [->,blue] node [midway,above,red,sloped] {to the top}     ([c]A) 
      edge [->,gray] node [midway,above,blue,sloped] {to the bottom} ([c]B)
    (C) ++(-0.5,0) -- +(0,3) node[midway,above,sloped] {correct!}
    (C) ++(-0.5,0) -- +(0,-3) node[midway,below,sloped] {also correct!};

  \foreach \myn  in {A,B}
    {
      \draw ([c]\myn) ++ (-8pt,0) -- (\myn)   ;
    }

\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
\foreach \offset in {-1.5,-1.0,-0.75,-0.5} {
  \MyTixZPicture{\offset in}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We can replicate the situation using less code as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {89.99,90.00,90.01} {
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(\a:1) node[midway,above,sloped] {\a};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, consider the output:

[image]

Up to 90°, the line leans ever so slightly to the right, which causes `above` to place the node "on the left". At 90°, it's a bit of a crapshoot, I suppose, but the behavior is consistent that 90° works "as expected". But anything greater than 90° leans ever so slightly to the *left*, which causes `above` to place the node "on the right".

So, in your original code, any small rounding error in the calculation of `($([c]A)!0.5!([c]B)$)` could cause the drawn path to lean slightly one way or the other, which causes the behavior you observed.

Here's a final example showing that an error of `1sp` (TeX's smallest unit) in the "vertical-ness" of a path is enough to cause this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {1,0,-1} {
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(\a sp,1) node[midway,above,sloped] {\a};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a workaround, avoid doing the shifting more than once: using the `|-` coordinate specifier instead will guarantee orthogonality, giving the desired result with minimal changes:

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\MyTixZPicture}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={xshift=#1}]

    \node [above left] at (0,0) {$\texttt{xshift}=#1$};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,label={right:B}] (B) at (0,-3in) {};  

  \node[circle,inner sep=1pt] 
    (C) at ($([c]A)!0.5!([c]B)$) {C} 
      edge [->,blue] node [midway,above,red,sloped] {to the top}     (C |- A) 
      edge [->,gray] node [midway,above,blue,sloped] {to the bottom} (C |- B);

  \foreach \myn  in {A,B}
    {
      \draw ([c]\myn) ++ (-8pt,0) -- (\myn)   ;
    }

\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
\foreach \offset in {-1.5,-1.0,-0.75,-0.5} {
  \MyTixZPicture{\offset in}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]